# Getting error Cannot resolve symbol Area

Tags: java, area

This is the following code

```
public class Logic
        public static double rectangleArea(double length, double width)
        {
           Area = length*width;
            System.out.println("Area: " + area);
            return area;
```

Answer (score 2):

From your code I assume you are writing in Java.
Suppose this will work:

```
public class Logic { 
    public static double rectangleArea(double length, double width) {
      double area = length*width; 
      System.out.println("Area: " + area); 
      return area;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must match the case of your variables.
Your equation uses an uppercase `Area` while your print statement uses lower case `area`.

You must also state the type of the variable (in this case, `double`).

Try this instead:

```
double area = length*width;
```